# Controller has not been initialized after routing to another page

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, provider

I have an app I am working on. I used sharedpreferences and provider to store the index of the pageview of the screen so that when I click on a button from the home page, it navigate to the PageViewScreen and will continue from the last index page of the pageView screen I was before leaving the app. How ever when I click on the button to navigate to the PageViewScreen, I always get "LateInitializationError: Field 'controller' has not been initialized.". but when I hot reload, the error dissapear.

here is my provider and shared preference file

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ProviderData extends ChangeNotifier {
  SharedPreferences? prefs;
  final String pageIndexKey = 'pageIndex';
  int? _pageIndex;

  ProviderData() {
    _pageIndex = 0;
    loadFromPrefs();
  }

  _initPrefs() async {
    prefs ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  loadFromPrefs() async {
    await _initPrefs();
    _pageIndex = prefs!.getInt(pageIndexKey) ?? 0;
    notifyListeners();
    return _pageIndex;
  }

  _savePageIndexToPrefs({required String key, required int value}) async {
    await _initPrefs();
    prefs!.setInt(key, value);
  }

  void changePageIndex(int newPageIndex) {
    _pageIndex = newPageIndex;

    _savePageIndexToPrefs(key: pageIndexKey, value: _pageIndex!);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and here is the button that leads to the pageview screen

```
  SizedBox(
              width: 350,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {

/////route here
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => PageViewScreen()));

/////
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(215, 60, 16, 1),
                  textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                ),
                child: Text("Continue"),
              ),
            ),
```

below is my PageView Screen,

I initialize my pageView controller below and I assign a value to the page controller and get the last index in the initState.

```
  late final PageController controller;

 @override
  void initState() {
    ProviderData().loadFromPrefs().then((value) {
      controller = PageController(initialPage: value);
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

and here is finally where I used the controller in my PageViewScreen;

```
 Consumer<ProviderData>(
            builder: (context, providerData, child) {
              return PageView(

// I use the controller here and some other places in the code,
                controller: controller,
//
                onPageChanged: (index) {
                  providerData.changePageIndex(index);
                  setState(() {
                    onLastPage = index == 2;
                    onFirstPage = index == 0;
                    onSecondPage = index == 1;
                    onThirdPage = index == 2;
                    onFourthPage = index == 3;
                    onFifthPage = index == 4;
                    onSixthPage = index == 5;
                    onSeventhPage = index == 6;
                  });
                },
                children: _pageList,
              );
            },
          ),
```

The main problem is having initialization error after clicking on the button that leads to the PageViewScreen.  on hot reload, the initialization error disappear and the code controller works perfectly. But I am looking for a solution to not get the late initialization error while moving to the PageView.

Please I need someone that can help me solve this issue.

Thank you in advance

I have tried to confirm that I have initialized the controller

Comment: `ProviderData().loadFromPrefs()` completes later than the build method runs, therefore at the first time your code reads `controller` before it gets its value. That's what the error means. I suggest to wrap `Consumer<ProviderData>` into a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help but I do not know how to wrap my consumer<ProviderData> into futureBuilder. Please can you help me with an example with code?. Thank you

Comment: Check out [this guide](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), it is explained there with example code.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. I later found out that I didn't wrap one of the widgets with consumer.. Although I still have an error with the the late initialization but the code app didn't break

Answer (score 0):

Place your initialization code below super.initState();

```
     late final PageController controller;
      @override
      void initState() {
         super.initState();
         ProviderData().loadFromPrefs().then((value) {
         controller = PageController(initialPage: value);
       });
     }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you but the error still persist when I place the initialization code below super.initState

Comment: try removing final

Comment: Thank you.. I have fixed it to some extent